# Zimbra - scheduled mail sending

Tags: email, schedule, zimbra, zimlet

I was thinking about making a Zimlet that would send mails on specific dates(name dates automatically etc.)m but can't find any way to do so.

I know that exporting from zimbra is not a problem, but is importing scheduled events like this even possible?
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

Zimbra has no built-in Event system. Still, using *cronjobs*, a *zimlet* and a *script*, that uses the Zimbra-API, this could be achieved.

The *Zimlet* would function as a setup ui, where users can create the mails, that should be sent regularly.

The *script* then uses the Zimbra-API to fetch these informations and send the mails.

The script, in turn, is called via a *cronjob*.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to schedule emails in Zimbra, on the send button if you click on the arrow next to it a drop down list appears with an option to schedule email for some time in the future, you will see it then in the drafts section until the time is reached to send it